# how to compare two arrays and return true in js

Tags: javascript

I'm comparing with the two arrays and if one of the array of the element matches with the other array of the element it should return the `true`

```
var data1 = ["ram","krishna"]
var data2 = ["", "ram"]
const isInArray = dat1.includes(data2)
```

I used the `some` but i'm getting the value of `["ram"]`

Comment: _"I used the `some` but i'm getting the value of `["ram"]`"_ - `.some()` returns a boolean, hence this is not possible.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` and `includes` and then check the length.

```js
var data1 = ["ram","krishna"]
var data2 = ["", "ram"]
const isInArray = data1.filter(value => data2.includes(value)).length ? true : false;
console.log(isInArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data1 = ["ram","krishna"]
var data2 = ["", "ram"]
const isInArray = data1.some((elem) => data2.includes(elem))
console.log(isInArray)
```